# How to add a ConstraintLayout to a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

as the title states, i do have two Elements:

1. LinearLayout:

   ```
       <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/idContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.384"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.419"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. ConstraintsLayout

   ```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res                                               `/android"`

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/idExample">

     <EditText
            android:id="@+id/iddas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="date"
           />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   ```

**Quesiton**: How to add the ConstraintLayout to the LinearLayout?

**What i tried:**

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.idContent);
ConstraintsLayout cst = (ConstraintsLayout) findViewById(R.id.idExample);
linear.addView(cst);
```

**Issue:** **Error:** Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup

Comment: Why don't you do it in XML?

Comment: use LayoutInflater  to inflate view and add it to your linear layout or 
use view stubs that would be better approach.

Comment: No, view stubs are only for one time view, i need the ability however, to change the content of linearLayout each time a function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is `null` because it has never been inflated. Assume the layout that contains the `ConstraintsLayout` is `my_layout.xml`, now you should inflate it first, then add it to the `LinearLayout`:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View cst = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
linear.addView(cst);
```

Comment: yes, tried out `ConstraintLayout cst = (ConstraintLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.constraintsLayout, linear);`    there is an Error: `android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLay`

Comment: It seems like the `ConstraintLayout` was the root in its xml layout. However, I updated the answer. Please check again.

Comment: `View cst = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout);` - requires two arguments, i gave it as  `layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.constraintsLayout, linear)` - which seemingly leads to the error.